# How to make a column with a list of unique values in a column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have Column A with some values, and I would like to make a new column B consisting of list of the unique values in column A.

If the values in the column A are 1,2 and 3, what I would like to make is a column with values like "1, 2, 3" for all the rows. The result should look like this:

```
Col_A  Col_B
1     "1,2,3"
2     "1,2,3"
3     "1,2,3"
1     "1,2,3"
3     "1,2,3"
```

As shown above, I wanted the new column to look like what it would look like with paste() command: `paste(1, 2, 3 sep = ",")`.

I would really appreciate it if anyone could offer a solution that could work in piped codes %>%, but any suggestion is more than welcome!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Col_A = c(1:3, 1, 3))
df %>% mutate(Col_B = toString(unique(Col_A))) 

#  Col_A   Col_B
#1     1 1, 2, 3
#2     2 1, 2, 3
#3     3 1, 2, 3
#4     1 1, 2, 3
#5     3 1, 2, 3
```

and in base R :

```
transform(df, Col_B = toString(unique(Col_A)))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Col_B := toString(unique(Col_A))]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would want a column "*consisting of list of the unique values in column A.*" but here is one option:

```
library(magrittr) # for pipes
df$Col_B <- df$Col_A %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  list()

str(df)
# 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ Col_A: int  1 2 3 1 3
#  $ Col_B:List of 5
#   ..$ : int  1 2 3
#   ..$ : int  1 2 3
#   ..$ : int  1 2 3
#   ..$ : int  1 2 3
#   ..$ : int  1 2 3
```

Input data:

```
df <- data.frame(Col_A = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L))
```